# Nextcord AttributeError

Tags: python, discord, aiohttp, nextcord

This error has happened ever since I changes the API requests to async using aiohttp and I really dont understand what is happening I have all I know its saying  `coroutine` object has no attribute `edit` I'm hoping someone might able to figure this out but I am still going to be trying myself, if you can see the issue could you explain it to me thank you.

```
class SeedPingHLL(commands.Cog):

    
    def __init__(self, legionnaire):

        self.legionnaire = legionnaire
        self.check_to_start_seed_ping.start()


    #Here were passing a loop into the view embed and updating when new players have joined will update enbeded view to new player count until seeding completed
    @tasks.loop(time=Start_seeding_time)
    async def check_to_start_seed_ping(self):
        print("Task started")
        while True:
            ##need a while loop and stops the while loop but is ready for the next time!
            players = await api_request_public()
            event_check = await Seed_API()
            min_player_count = await Seed_API()
            #if event_check[0] == False and self.seed_ping_hll.is_running() == False:
            if event_check[0] == False and self.seed_ping_hll.is_running() == False:
                if players[1] >= 1:
                #if players[1] >= min_player_count[1]:
                    print("started")
                    seed_channel = self.legionnaire.get_channel(Channel_id)
                    seed_ping = seed_channel.send(embed=await Seed_Ping_Embed())
                    
                    self.seed_ping_hll.start(seed_ping)
                    break
            #await asyncio.sleep(1.0)
            
    
    @tasks.loop(minutes=1.0)
    async def seed_ping_hll(self, seed_ping_message):
        
        player_count_end_seeding = await Seed_API()

        players = await api_request_public()
        
        await seed_ping_message.edit(embed =Seed_Ping_Embed())
        await asyncio.sleep(0.3)
        print("player checked")

        if players[1] > player_count_end_seeding[2]:
            seed_ping_message.edit(embed = await Seed_Ping_Embed(server_seeded=True,))
            print("stopping")
            self.seed_ping_hll.cancel()
            players_vip_reward_check()
```

Terminal error:

```
sys:1: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Messageable.send' was never awaited
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-25' coro=<Loop._loop() done, defined at C:\Users\shazd\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\lost-legionnaire-9AFMHyBb-py3.12\Lib\site-packages\nextcord\ext\tasks\__init__.py:128> exception=TypeError('Loop._error() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given')>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\shazd\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\lost-legionnaire-9AFMHyBb-py3.12\Lib\site-packages\nextcord\ext\tasks\__init__.py", line 145, in _loop
    await self.coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\shazd\lost-legionnaire\lost_legionnaire\cogs\SeedPingHLL.py", line 78, in seed_ping_hll
    seed_ping_message.edit(embed = await Seed_Ping_Embed())
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'coroutine' object has no attribute 'edit'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\shazd\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\lost-legionnaire-9AFMHyBb-py3.12\Lib\site-packages\nextcord\ext\tasks\__init__.py", line 173, in _loop
    await self._call_loop_function("error", exc)
  File "C:\Users\shazd\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\lost-legionnaire-9AFMHyBb-py3.12\Lib\site-packages\nextcord\ext\tasks\__init__.py", line 120, in _call_loop_function
    await coro(self._injected, *args, **kwargs)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: Loop._error() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

I have added await to functions that needed it but with the  `coroutine` object has no attribute `edit` I don't know what the issue could be now as it was at first an await issue now I have no clue.

Comment: It's still an await issue. A coroutine is the object returned from an async function, which (typically) must then be awaited on. From your small fragment of code, it's not entirely obvious to me how it works, but maybe you should be awaiting `seed_channel.send()`? Otherwise, work your way back and figure out where that coroutine object came from.

Comment: I fixed it, and I dont understand enough to explain it on a basic level but I will show my findings

Answer (score 0):

So changing an API requests back to using requests and then adding in await before sending messaging to the channel here

```
seed_ping = await seed_channel.send(embed= Seed_Ping_Embed())
```

and

```
await seed_ping_message.edit(embed=Seed_Ping_Embed())
```

This seemed to have worked